# How to get list of recently created, deleted and updated files in Webdav

Tags: synchronization, webdav

I've had a look at the webdav spec but can't find this information.

Let's say I download all the webdav files on my computer, then later someone delete a file from the webdav server. Is there a way to find out that a file has been deleted without re-downloading all the files and manually comparing them?

I guess what I have in mind is something like the delta api of Dropbox or OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

"without re-downloading all the files"

You can PROPFIND the files and compare ETags and/or last-modified dates.

Also, you never need to re-download in HTTP if you do a conditional request (see https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7232.html)